# Затемнение экрана за модальным окном

Tags: jquery

Доброго времени суток! У меня есть всплывающее окно, как сделать, чтобы экран затемнялся, когда оно всплывает?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Сделайте слой-подкладку, который будет ниже слоя модального окна.
[Простой пример](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/r89Pd/). Понятное дело, что затемнение можно [сделать анимированным](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/r89Pd/2/) или придумать что-то своё. Это уже зависит от той степени извращения, которое вам присуще )))